# Permission(ACL) middleware for Multer that acts based on multipart/form-data parameters

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, authorization, multer

In my `Express.js` REST API, I'm using **multer** to upload images into server's static folder with `diskStorage`. I have wanted to build a **generic** file upload page for both users and admins. Detailed use case is as follows:

- choose a `category` from a drop-down list
- write an valid `id` in the form field,
- choose a valid `image(file)` and submit.
- if regular user (with `isAdmin==false`) selects `category` different than `users` , then the API responds with a 403 and won't upload the image at all.

What I want to achieve is to allow only users with `isAdmin==true` to upload images for the all categories. But, within the same route, regular users can only upload images for the `users` category.

The question is how to get access to the `req.body.category` inside authentication & authorization middleware and reject upload process pre-flight?

I need to check `category` and `isAdmin` fields at the same time to make decision about giving permission for upload process or not.

### React-side

```
const formData = new FormData()

formData.append('id', this.state.id)
formData.append('category', this.state.category)
formData.append('photo', this.state.file)

this.props.fileUpload(formData)
```

### Express-side

**Router**

```
router.post('/upload', AuthController.role('admin'), UploadController.uploadPhoto);
```

**AuthController**

```
public static role(role: any) {
  return (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    if (role === 'admin') {
      console.dir(req.body); // req.body prints { user_id: 1, isAdmin: true }
    // cannot decide whether give access to the route or not over here because we don't know the req.body.category yet.
      if (req.body && req.body.isAdmin) {
        next();
      } else {
        return res.status(403).send(new Unauthorized());
      }
    }
   };
 }
```

**UploadController**

```
const imageFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  console.dir(req.body); // prints { id: '1', category: 'users' } cannot access req.body.isAdmin over here
  if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
    return cb(new Error('Only image files are allowed!'), false);
  }
  cb(null, true);
};

const upload = util.promisify(multer({ storage, fileFilter: imageFilter, limits: {fileSize: MAX_SIZE} })
                                                                                  .single('photo'));
export class UploadController {
  public static async uploadPhoto(req: any, res: Response, next: NextFunction) { 
    // req.body.isAdmin is available over here    
    try {
      await upload(req, res);
      imageUrl = `${HOST}/static/${req.file.filename}`;
    } catch (e) {
      return res.status(400).send(new BadRequest('Image upload operation is not successful.'));
 }
}
```

**UPDATE:** My current workaround solution is to save the image temporarily and then check the `category` and `isAdmin` at the same time when they become available.

```
try {
     await upload(req, res);
     ....
     ..
     // Now req.body.category and req.body.isAdmin are both available here
 }
```